# Triangle Quiz Cant Able to figureout how to do this

Tags: javascript

Directions:
For this quiz, you're going to create a function called buildTriangle() that will accept an input (the triangle at its widest width) and will build a triangle. See the example output below.

buildTriangle(10);
Returns
https://ibin.co/3Dv8ajw80RxV.png
see image

We've given you one function makeLine() to start with. The function takes in a line length, and builds a line of asterisks and returns the line with a newline character.

```
function makeLine(length) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    line += "* "
  }
  return line + "\n";
}
```

You will need to call this makeLine() function in buildTriangle().

This will be the most complicated program you've written yet, so take some time thinking through the problem before diving into the code. What tools will you need from your JavaScript tool belt? Professionals plan out their code before writing anything. Think through the steps your code will need to take and write them down in order. Then go through your list and convert each step into actual code. Good luck!

```
my code!!
/*
 * Programming Quiz: Build A Triangle (5-3)
 */

// creates a line of * for a given length
let line;
function makeLine(length) {
     line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return console.log(line + "\n");
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.

function buildTriangle(num) {
    for(var i = 1;i < num+1;i++) {
        makeLine(i);

    }
}

buildTriangle(10);
```

can it be better using only functions and loops no extra crazy stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you were meant to (and certainly it's not necessary to) change the `makeLine()` function at all. Since it returns the single line as a string, you simply have to receive that in the caller and act on it somehow.

In other words, your loop is *exactly* what you need (kudos for that) but, using the original function, it would be something like:

```
function buildTriangle(num) {
    var triangle = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {        // add each line in turn.
        triangle += makeLine(i);
    }
    return triangle;                       // return the whole thing.
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));            // or alert if you prefer.
```

You'll notice that I slightly changed your `for` loop end condition, I think it makes more sense this way (one through N inclusive, not one inclusive through N+1 exclusive).

And, since you're *building* a triangle, you shouldn't be printing it within the functions. Function names should reflect what they do (which is also why I think it's a bad idea to change `makeLine()` so that it outputs the line).

Rather, the built triangle should be returned to the caller where they can do whatever they wish with it. In this case, that means printing it, but they may want to attach it to an email, save it to a file, or use it as an encryption key :-).

Comment: nice thanks but one way to clean the code
`triangle += makeLine(i);`

Comment: Good point, @Rishabh, I originally tailored it to a specific skill level but I've just noticed the original function used `+=` anyway, so obviously your educator thinks that's okay. I've changed it as per your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

function buildTriangle(num){
    var triangle = "";
    for(var i = 1 ; i<=num ; i++){
        triangle+= makeLine(i);
    }
    return triangle;
}

console.log(buildTriangle(20));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.